# In hadoop, how to verify number of map tasks running on each slave node individually?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera

I have a Hadoop cluster with head node as master and 7 other nodes configured as slaves each have 8 cores and 8 GB memory. I am playing around with varying the parameter "mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum" and number of slaves in the slaves configuration file. Now, if my program has to run say 40 tasks, can I see how many tasks ran on each individual slave nodes in some log file or somewhere? Basically, I am looking for Map task distribution among different nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way you can do this is from the web interface shipped with the Hadoop system.

In you web browser, type in: ***jobtrack-machine-hostname:50030*** For example: ***localhost:50030***

And you will get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can install Ganglia to monitor statistics from the jobtracker.  I did this on my cluster and it was very easy to install.  It also allows you to monitor load, swap, disk, memory usage, etc. on each node.

See the instructions here: http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/GangliaMetrics

GOTCHA ALERT: If you're installing Ganglia you're probably going to get version 3.1   Make sure that you use `org.apache.hadoop.metrics.ganglia.GangliaContext31` instead of what they have on that page.